# How can I get \maketitle to create a separate title page with the article class?

Tags: formatting, titles, document-classes, article

I am working on a maths assignment and new to using LaTeX.  I have written the assignment up, but I would like the title page to be its own page.  Currently my title page is a few lines generated by `\title` and `\author`, but it then goes straight on to my first `\section` content.

My assignment's `\documentclass` is `article`.

The code that generated the title and section is this:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Section header}
```

How can I create the title page so that it is completely on its own separate page and not shared with the section?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `article` class recognises the `titlepage` option, which forces the `\maketitle` command to create a separate page.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\author{A.\,N.~Other}
\title{Some things I did}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some text
\end{document}
```