# How can I get a title page with the LaTeX article class?

Tags: titles, article

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get \maketitle to create a separate title page with the article class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29440/how-can-i-get-maketitle-to-create-a-separate-title-page-with-the-article-class)

I'm trying to vertically center the title page and abstract in my LaTeX document (much like the `report` class does). I'm using the `article` class now. Essentially what I want is the `report` class without chapters, just sections and subsections etc.

Comment: Have a look at: [How can I get \maketitle to create a separate title page with the article class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29440/how-can-i-get-maketitle-to-create-a-separate-title-page-with-the-article-class).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 28):

Use the `titlepage` class option.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{(title)}
\author{(author)}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: what does this class do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

By default, section-level numbering is defined in [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) as

```
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
```

which prepends the section number with `\thechapter.`. The other lower-level sectioning commands follow a similar hierarchy. As such, you could just use the `report` document class and remove the `\chapter` numbering from (all) the lower-level sectioning commands (like `\section` and `\subsection`) using

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

Other chapter-related may also require redefinition, although this is not technically necessary. For example, `\theequation`, `\thefigure` and `\thetable` all condition on the value of the `chapter` counter, prepending it with `\thechapter.` only if `\c@chapter>\z@` (`chapter` counter is greater than zero, which is only incremented from `0` at the first sign of `\chapter`). Regardless and for completeness:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
```

Here's a minimal example (without anything special) that just shows the sectioning structure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\author{A.\ Nonymous} \title{My title} \date{\today}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{First section} \lipsum[1]
\subsection{First subection} \lipsum[2]
\subsection{Second subsection} \lipsum[3]
\subsubsection{First subsubsection} \lipsum[4]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: One would also have to redefine `\thefigure` and `\thetable`.

Comment: @lockstep: Didn't think of that... thanks. I'll elaborate and add. However, it seems not to be necessary since `report` conditions on whether `\c@chapter>\z@` which helps.