# How to get the code on a single page

Tags: formatting, titles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get \maketitle to create a separate title page with the article class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29440/how-can-i-get-maketitle-to-create-a-separate-title-page-with-the-article-class)

Hi I am new to Latex and am trying to create a latex document with the following preamble and content.

While, the code produces the desired output, somehow all the output comes on page 2, leaving page 1 totally blank.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\topmargin 0pt
\advance \topmargin by -\headheight
\advance \topmargin by -\headsep
\textheight 8.9in
\usepackage{enumerate}
\oddsidemargin 0pt
\evensidemargin \oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth 0.5in
\textwidth 6.5in

\begin{document}

\title{ MISC \\
Homework II \\
Computer Science \\Fall 2011\\}
\date{ September 17, 2011 }

\begin{center}
\begin{Large}
\maketitle{All the code here is entirely mine}\\
\end{Large}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Could someone help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong.

P.S. If I dont center my title, the output does show on a single page, but the formatting is not very presentable.

Comment: Don't use the `center` environment as it adds vertical space. Instead use `\centering`. See [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables).

Comment: @PeterGrill: that is only important if you have another command which adds also  vertical space like `\caption`. In the above example it is correct to use the environment `center`

Comment: This looks very much like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29440/how-can-i-get-maketitle-to-create-a-separate-title-page-with-the-article-class

Answer (score 1):

`\maketitle` takes no arguments. To get the desired output, the code is

```
\begin{document}

\title{ MISC \\
Homework II \\
Computer Science \\Fall 2011\\}
\date{ September 17, 2011 }

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{Large}
All the code here is entirely mine
\end{Large}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Note that the title and date definition may be done in the preamble, that is, before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code: `\maketitle` does not take any arguments. It just print the title, author, data data according to the predefined style. For `article` the title is on the same page as the text.  You can use the `titlepage` option for the document class `article` or switch to `report` class.

The `\\` in the line of `\maketitle` is useless.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\topmargin 0pt
\advance \topmargin by -\headheight
\advance \topmargin by -\headsep
\textheight 8.9in
\usepackage{enumerate}
\oddsidemargin 0pt
\evensidemargin \oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth 0.5in
\textwidth 6.5in



\begin{document}

\title{ MISC \\
Homework II \\
Computer Science \\
Fall 2011}
\date{ September 17, 2011 }
\author{Your Name\thanks{All the code in this report is entirely mine}}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the environment `titlepage` if you want to create your own title and set the margins with package `geometry`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textheight=8.9in,textwidth=6.5in,marginparwidth=0.5in}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}    

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\Large
MISC \\
Homework II \\
Computer Science \\Fall 2011

\vspace{1cm}
September 17, 2011

\vspace{1cm}
All the code here is entirely mine
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

next page
\end{document}
```