# Titlepage in article class when two-sided

Tags: titles, double-sided, article

I am having troubles to set up a title page with article class.

My problem is same than here, but in addition to this example, I am using a two-sided document. If I add titlepage option here, the titlepage is not aligned in middle but aligned in twoside-style. However, for printing, I would prefer a middle-aligned titlepage. How is this possible?

[How can I get \maketitle to create a separate title page with the article class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29440/how-can-i-get-maketitle-to-create-a-separate-title-page-with-the-article-class)

```
\documentclass[titlepage,twoside]{article}

\begin{document}

\title{An example}
\author{Me}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

\section{First Section}
Hello world.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the title in the middle.

Comment: You can create the titlepage separately with its own geometry and include it in your document using `pdfpages`.

Comment: Please, don't use `\maketitle` inside the `titlepage` environment, it is just wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `geometry` package and fix `hmarginratio` and later restore the original layout.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}       %% showframe just for demo

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{hmarginratio=1:1}    %% make layout symmetric
\title{An example}
\author{Me}
\date{Today}
\maketitle
\restoregeometry              %% restore the layout
\section{First Section}
Hello world.

\end{document}
```

[image]