# Which core document classes recognise the titlepage option?

Tags: formatting, titles, document-classes

I've stumpled over [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29443/119907) to another problem, and it states:

> The `article` class recognises the `titlepage` option, which forces the `\maketitle` command to create a separate page.

To me the wording of this sentence implies that there *possibly may be* document classes which do not recognise the `titlepage` option. Hence my question is:

Which core document classes support the `titlepage` option and which do not?
(And for those classes that do not support this option: Which of them put the title on a separate page by default?)

Comment: Hint: Take any document class you care about -- there are hundreds, if not thousands, out there, and I don't have the slightest idea which ones you may care about -- and include `titlepage` among the options set via the `\documentclass[...]{<name of class>}` instruction. If LaTeX issues a warning that the option `titlepage` wasn't used, bingo!, you know it's not set up to use this option. Of course, (almost) anyone can set up a document class and set up an option called `titlepage`. The crux is, *what does the document class do* if this option is set?

Comment: The question may have been a bit unclear in that regard. I am only interested in the core classes that every LaTeX distribution should provide by default.

Comment: "the core classes every LaTeX distribution should provide by default" still leaves 100 or more possibilities. (Most LaTeX distributions are quite large...) Did you see the posting [What are the available “documentclass” types and their uses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782/5001)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard to answer. Anyone can write a latex class and they may or may not have a titlepage option.

Of the classes in the core distribution,

`article`, `report`, `proc`, `slides` and `book` have a `titlepage` option,

`letter` and `minimal` do not have `titlepage` option or `titlepage` environment or `\maketitle`

`ltnews` is based on `article` but removes the `titlepage` option via

```
\DeclareOption{titlepage}{\OptionNotUsed}
```

`ltxdoc` class is based on `article` and inherits its options.